# Remote Erlang node debugging not working using OTP Debugger

Tags: erlang, remote-debugging, erlang-otp, epmd

**Setup:**

I am using the OTP Debugger for debugging an Erlang process as explained in https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/debugger/debugger_chapter.html

I started epmd using `epmd -daemon -d`.

I started the application in a separate node as follows;

```
$ erl -sname node1 -eval "maths:f1()"
```

I started the Debugger in a separate node as follows;

```
$erl -sname node2
(node2@vm-alarm)1> debugger: start(global).
{ok,<0.88.0>}
Added the module in the Monitor window using Module-->Interpret
Added a few breakpoints using MonitorWindow-->Break menu
```

Both the nodes are listed in the "`empd -names`" command.

**Issue**

I am unable to debug the application which is running in node1. It is not listed in the Debugger's monitor window in order to attach.

The issue is not seen when I run the application and the Debugger in a single node.

Comment: Does it work if you ping the remote node before starting debugger? That would be `net_adm:ping('node1@vm-alarm').`

Comment: Thanks @legoscia. I got a successful response (pong)